# How to plot different standard deviations for each point in the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have a list of 12 lists, such that within each of those inner lists the first element is a mean of temperatures for the corresponding month of the year and the second element is the standard deviation of temperatures for that month. How should I plot this using matplotlib such that I am able to draw a line graph of the means of all the months, and also show their corresponding standard deviations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the means and standard deviations using list comprehensions and plot the result using `plt.errorbar` ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html)).

## Example

```py
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: mean_and_sd = [(0, 2), (3, 6), (2, 3), (7, 2)]

In [3]: means = [inner_list[0] for inner_list in mean_and_sd]

In [4]: standard_devs = [inner_list[1] for inner_list in mean_and_sd]

In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: plt.errorbar(x=np.arange(len(means)), y=means, yerr=standard_devs)
Out[6]: <ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>

In [7]: plt.show()
```

Gives

[image: Plotted means and standard deviations]